# How do I switch div layers with a timeout function in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

members of the Angular Technorati. I come to you with a puzzling issue, although simple. I need to switch out a div layer after about 11 seconds and show another div layer. How is this done using angularjs timeout service, preferably within a controller?

Ok, what if I combined a show and hide event with the $timeou service?

```
`  <body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="showHideController"  ng-init="getPanel_1()">




  <div  ng-controller="showHideController" ng-show="divA"style=''>


</div>



<div ng-controller="showHideController" ng-show="divB" style=''>
</div>
<script>
 angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('showHideController',function($scope, $timeout) {


  $scope.getPanel_1 = function(){
  $scope.divA = true;
  $scope.divB = false;
  $scope.divC = false; 
  }
  $timeout(function (){
  $scope.getPanel_1 = function(){
  $scope.divA = false;
  $scope.divB = true;
  $scope.divC = false; 
  }
  }, 5000);
});

</script>`
```

Thanks in advance,
Batoe.

"The road to success is filled with obstacles......but also success!"
The unknown optimist.

Comment: by "switch out" do you mean change the `z-index` inline style? you can use `ngStyle` for that https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle or `ngClass` if you have predefined styles https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Use ng-show directives and show/hide the div according to your settings

Answer (score 0):

Not very angularjs way, but you could:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-include src="currentDiv">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="div1.html">
    <div ng-controller="panel_1">
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="div2.html">
    <div ng-controller="panel_2">
    </div>
</script>
```

and in your controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.currentDiv= "div1.html" ;

    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.currentDiv= "div2.html" ;
    }, 15000);
});
```

Comment: Clever, but it didn't switch the divs. I think if I can combine an show/hide event with the $timeout service, it might be the answer, I looking for.

Comment: so you want some kind of animation on div switch?

Comment: Yes, but I can make that happen with angular's  Animate service or jquery. I just need to show and hide the initial div layer after about ten seconds. It is the only time period in my app where I will need this to function.